# Helm grep is too slow

Tags: helm, helm-projectile

Whenever I use helm-grep, helm-ag, or helm-ack, some results show up faster than others. In some cases the search completes after several minutes. Is it because I have to create some sort of index? If yes, how do I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try ivy-mode, here is a grep example written by ivy-mode's developer.

http://oremacs.com/2015/04/19/git-grep-ivy/

I turn to ivy-mode because helm is too slow.

Answer (score 1):

I had many griefs with helm-git-grep and helm-ack but I did like the basic interface.  I've since switched to helm-grepint.

https://github.com/kopoli/helm-grepint